# regex parsing request from api python

Tags: python, regex, api

i have python script and getting responce from api, responce style is like this

```
?{"res":"yes","info":{"name":"name surname \/ name surname"}}
```

how can i show only name and surname?

```
import requests
number1 = input("nomeri ")
num = "number"
params = {}
params[num]= number1

var = requests.post('api', data = params)


print(var.text)
```

Comment: Is it a dictonary? If so, then what is that `?`, in the front?

Comment: i dont know i getting this responce i think its dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over what the python api responds, you can split out name and surname in the api itself, and assign them to keys "name" and "surname"

else do something like

```
dict_obj = {"res":"yes","info":{"name":"name surname \/ name surname"}}
name_str = dict_obj["info"]["name"].split('\/').strip()
name_list = name_str.split(" ")
name = name_list[0]
surname = name_list[1]
```

Comment: There is a `?` in front of the dictonary..
Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: So, you aren't sure about it?

Comment: ? in front of dictionary might be just a typo, irrelevant from the question being asked

Comment: You may be right, but read the question..it states that regex is to be used.

Comment: dict_obj = var.text
name_str = dict_obj["info"]["name"].split('\/').strip()
name_list = name_str.split(" ")
name = name_list[0]
surname = name_list[1]
print(name + surname )

Comment: Can you tell me what you did, and why is there a ? in your piece of code?

Comment: i dont know, api what gave is written in php, maybe its from this

Comment: How are you calling the php api from python, you need to be more clear in your question, and provide more details there.

Comment: i just sending request and getting responce and just want to cut name and surname with regex, i dont understand why is this important

Comment: So your response is a string ```"?{"res":"yes","info":{"name":"name surname \/ name surname"}}"```

Comment: Okay so the string is `?{"res":"yes","info":{"name":"name surname \/ name surname"}}` is that correct @whatlOol ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a dictionary, you don't need regex to get name and surname. Just do:

```
dic = {'res':'yes','info':{'name':"name surname \/ name surname}}
res = dic['info']['name']
name_surname = res{:res.index('\\')]
```

I also wonder what the "?" is? Hope i work!

Comment: same string indices must be integers